# Do you have any children applying with you?

Tags: uk-visa

I mistakenly answered YES, where the question was asked if " Do you have any children applying with you?
Meanwhile, My partner is not with me in the UK, she's not applying anytime soon. I have done capturing already.
what can I do?

Please do advise.

Comment: What is *capturing*? What type of visa are you applying for? Have you checked whether you can cancel the application and start afresh?

Comment: @Traveller I assume "capturing" is the photo and fingerprint scanning taken at a biometrics appointment.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, Thanks for your response, Capturing means an appointment to capture a photo and finger print. I was actually switching my Tier4 Visa to Health and Care Skilled workers Visa Tier2.  I answered yes because I want my family to be a dependant on my visa in future. I have gone for finger print and photo appointment. what can i do?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica "Because you...are applying from outside the UK": on the contrary, this appears to be an application for an in-country switch.

Comment: @phoog That makes perfect sense, thank you. I didn't see that possibility. I'll delete my incorrect comments.

Answer (score 1):

This page https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa explains your options, depending on:

- the type of visa you’ve applied for
- how you were told to prove your identity when you started your online application

**If you were told to attend an appointment and have not yet given your fingerprints and photo**

You can cancel your application online and your fee will be refunded if you have not yet given your fingerprints and photo.

**If you were told to attend an appointment and have already given your fingerprints and photo**

If you applied within the UK, fill in the online form to withdraw your application.

If you applied outside the UK, contact UKVI to withdraw your application.

Your fee will not usually be refunded.

Comment: But is it in fact necessary to withdraw the application?  Perhaps the error is harmless.